# Django QuerySet: Why can't I filter an annotated QuerySet?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to retrieve a list of the 100 most popular books in my db, and then create a list of unique categories that are in that list. Here are my simplified Book, Favorite, and Category models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I can easily get a list of the 100 most popular books using the following query:

```
books =  Book.objects.annotate(num_favorites=Count('favorite')).order_by('-num_favorites')[:100]
```

But where I start having problems is when I try to get a list of unique categories for those 100 most popular books. The following query does not work (error posted below) and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
>>> categories = Category.objects.filter(book__in=books).distinct()
>>> categories


FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'num_favorites' into field. Choices are: category, favorite, id, name
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be piling too many things into one query. Try splitting it:

```
book_ids = (Book.objects.annotate(num_favorites=Count('favorite'))
    .order_by('-num_favorites')[:100].values_list('id', flat=True))
categories = Category.objects.filter(book__in=book_ids).distinct()
```

Comment: thanks @Mike, i tried that and the first query `book_ids = (Book.objects.annotate(num_favorites=Count('favorite'))
    .order_by('-num_favorites')[:100].values_list('id', flat=True))
` gives me the same error: `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'num_favorites' into field.` Really puzzling...

Comment: i can get a multi-field values list using `books_list = Book.objects.annotate(num_favorites=Count('favorite')).order_by('-num_favorites')[:100].values_list('id', 'num_favorites')` but this gives me a `TypeError: Cannot use a multi-field ValuesListQuerySet as a filter value.` error when I try to find the unique Categories.

Comment: Can you do `list(Book.objects.annotate(num_favorites=Count('favorite')).order_by('-num_favorites')[:100])`?

Comment: that works! thanks! any idea why this doesn't work with QuerySets?

Comment: It may be that it's too complex for Django to figure out the SQL as one query. Remember that Django has to limit itself to whatever works in all the different SQLs out there.

Comment: I've lost the link, but in the Django docs it says that evaluating a query to a list of IDs and passing it to a `__in=` filter is often the better implementation, as opposed to One Big Query.